# Why doesn't my php-file receive data from the javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

When i send data from the javascript to the php-file, it's doesn't look like it would receive the data from the post, what am I doing wrong?

```
//The javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#send").click(function() {                
      var source1='test';
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {source1: source1},
      });
    });
 });

//The PHP file - test.php
<?php $test = $_POST['source1']; print $test; ?>
```

Comment: Try with: `data: {'source1': source1};`

Comment: how do you know it is not? Do you view the network tab and check the response? Your test file just prints and you have nothing defined in the success so on the front end nothing will happen. Also, that rogue , after source1} might make IE cry

Comment: @KaiQing i think OP just want to send the $_POST params for use of test.php, but of-course it wont work since hes testing `test.php` page and the $_POST params will not be there when he starts testing it.

Comment: that's why I ask how he knows. Viewing the network tab will show him what the response is in the response tab. alternatively, he could add success: function(data){alert(data)} after the data property in the ajax call and it would actually do something on success

Comment: where do you want your result?

Comment: This is what i'm getting of errors:

ReferenceError: reference to undefined property M.cache jquery.min.js:19
POST http://www.xxxxx.nu/xxxx/test.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2688ms]

Comment: I want to send the javascript variable to the php-file, use it as a value for a php variable, when perform the task in the php-file and return the result.
- The part with return the result with javascript works fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove the final `,` after the data source. That will break your JS.

If that does't solve your issue, load up the developer tools of your browser and see if the XHR is being triggered.

It will be easier to debug from there.

A few other things: 
Source 1 should be in quotations.

Use `echo $test` or `print_r($test);` instead of `print`.
You can use this shorthand instead

```
var source1 = "test";
$.post( "test.php", { "source1": source1}, "json");
```

Comment: Trailing commas are valid, only IE (<9 iirc) breaks.